# Map two seperate array objects into one

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, mapping

So I have this scenario where I can have multiple calls to a service which returns some CMS strings and I need to merge all of these arrays together into a single object with one array

an example could be where I fetch two json objects (could be more);

https://www.fakeCmsUrl.com/bundle1
which conains;

```
{
"Text1":"Random1",
"Text2":"Random2",
"Text3":"Random3"
}
```

and https://www.fakeCmsUrl.com/bundle2
which conains;

```
{
"Label1":"weeee1",
"Label2":"weeee2",
"Labe3":"weeee3"
}
```

and somehow the outcome should be;

```
{
"Text1":"Random1",
"Text2":"Random2",
"Text3":"Random3",
"Label1":"weeee1",
"Label2":"weeee2",
"Labe3":"weeee3"
}
```

where they are merged together

So I've written this code where I succesfully merged these seperate calls and json objects to a singlone with two seperate arrays. But I just can't seem to get it to one array..

```
export async function getCmsBundles() {
    let cmsData = [];
    await
        axios.all([
            axios.get('https://www.fakeCmsUrl.com/bundle2'),
            axios.get('https://www.fakeCmsUrl.com/bundle1 ')
        ]).then(json => {
            Object.keys(json).forEach(res => {
                cmsData.push(json[res])
            })
        })
    console.log('----->', cmsData)
    return cmsData;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only plan on using 2 calls, you could deconstruct your array into variables with the arrow function parameters and then merge them into a single object by deconstructing both objects :

```
export async function getCmsBundles() {
    const cmsData = [];
    await
        axios.all([
            axios.get('https://www.fakeCmsUrl.com/bundle2'),
            axios.get('https://www.fakeCmsUrl.com/bundle1 ')
        ]).then(([bundle1, bundle2]) => {
            cmsData = { ...bundle1, ...bundle2 }
        })

    console.log('----->', cmsData)
    return cmsData;
}
```

If you do not know how many calls you are going to make, you can use the reduce function instead to build up your object one element by one :

```
export async function getCmsBundles() {
    const cmsData = [];
    await
        axios.all([
            axios.get('https://www.fakeCmsUrl.com/bundle2'),
            axios.get('https://www.fakeCmsUrl.com/bundle1 ')
        ]).then(data => {
            cmsData = data.reduce((acc, val) => ({ ...val, ...acc }), {})
        })

    console.log('----->', cmsData)
    return cmsData;
}
```

Working example of the second solution :

```js
const data = [
    {
        "Text1": "Random1",
        "Text2": "Random2",
        "Text3": "Random3"
    },
    {
        "Label1": "weeee1",
        "Label2": "weeee2",
        "Label3": "weeee3"
    },
    {
        "stuff": "thing"
    }
]

const merge = data => data.reduce((acc, val) => ({ ...val, ...acc }), {})

console.log(merge(data))
```

Comment: The issue in this case is that I only want to add a new axios.get(url) and then it should handle the rest for me. in your case I need to add both the url and a new parameter for each new bundle I need to fetch. I want to avoid this scenario